# Can I put static files in ./static instead of ./public?

Tags: scala, playframework

I want static assets to be in URLs like `http://127.0.0.1:8300/static/app.js` and be stored in `./static` in my application.

I have put my file in `./static/app.js` and added to `./conf/routes`:

```
# Map static resources from the ./static folder to the /static URL path
GET  /static/*file      controllers.Assets.at(path="/static", file)
```

Hovever when i do a GET request on `http://127.0.0.1:8300/static/app.js` I get an error message:

```
Action Not Found
For request 'GET /static/app.js'
These routes have been tried, in this order:
GET/                  controllers.HomeController.index
GET/count             controllers.CountController.count
GET/message           controllers.AsyncController.message
GET/assets/$file<.+>  controllers.Assets.versioned(path:String = "/public", file:Asset)
GET/static/$file<.+>  controllers.Assets.at(path:String = "/static", file:String)
GET/users             controllers.UserController.users
```

Anyone know why it is not matching `GET/assets/$file<.+>` ?

I can of course put my assets in `./public/` as a workaround, but I was wondering why I can't put them in `./static/`